# Creating viewmodels for usercontrols, how to get access to "there data" from my main viewmodel

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, mvvm, viewmodel, mvvm-light

I am using MVVMLight with a WP7 app. I have created a Main view connected to a viewmodel. This main view has a number of of custom controls that i created. Now from my understanding each usercontrol must have its own individual viewmodel.

So i have my main view datacontext connected to its viewmodel and every usercontrol's datacontext pointing to its own viewmodel.

Problem is, how do i get access to my viewmodel data from my custom controls in my viewmodel for my main view.

I am a little confused.

I could use the messenger but this sounds way too much work just to get the viewmodels communication.

If anyone can lend a hand it would be really helpful or if anyone has any examples.

I don't see any documentation or recommendations on created usercontrols in mvvmlight.

Answer (score 0):

Inject your ViewModels to your Constructor and you should have access to the data for your separated view models.

Comment: Thanks, so where would i create my viewmodel for my user control? in VIewModelLocator, that means its loaded even if i am not using it. SO i could dynamically create in in the contructor of the main view but that means a parameterless contructor do hence i can't inject anything... Do you have an example or can you give more info. Thanks